# roscd is not working despite sourcing the workspace

Tags: ros, roscd, ros-package-path

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I added a workspace to `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` using:

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

(catkin_ws is the name of my workspace).

To check if it was actually added i typed:

```
echo $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH
```

and it did show the path to that workspace that i just added (which means it was correctly added to ros package path). But the problem is, when i use `roscd` to change directories inside this workspace it gives the error:

```
roscd: No such package/stack 'Directory_Name'.
```

Shouldn't  `roscd` be able to change/shift between directories just like `cd` because this workspace is already added to `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`? ( i shift between directories using `cd` for now).

EDIT: The output of *tree -d ~/catkin_ws* is available in the form of images here:
( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3YE3NToSaLQQ3g0S0s2MnVubkE/view?usp=sharing ) "Image1"
( https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3YE3NToSaLQLXJBUkhnSy1iZTQ/view?usp=sharing) "Image 2"

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/214691/roscd-is-not-working-despite-sourcing-the-workspace./) by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2015-07-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not 100% sure if this is your question, but I'll give it a go.

`roscd <packagename>` is used to move into a package. You cannot use it to move to arbitrary directories within your workspace. E.g. `roscd src` would end up with multiple conflicting directories.

You can however pass in directories relative to a package. So e.g. `roscd move_base/src` would work.

For more info, have a look at [the documentation](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbash#roscd).

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2015-07-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-07-28**:
Ok. I tried doing *roscd src/Mydirectory* when i was inside the sourced workspace. but it didnt take me to MyDirectory although it should have. shouldn't it?

THere was only one folder named *src* at this stage in the workspace so should there be any confusion as you suggested?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-28**:
Is this actually a [ROS package](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage)? I.e. does it have a `CMakeLists.txt` and a `package.xml`?
If not, this will not work.

Can you post the output of `tree -d ~/catkin_ws`? Please use the edit button below your question.

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-07-28**:
^Post Edited.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2015-07-28**:
If you have created the package `ros_wkshop` with `catkin_create_pkg`, you should be able to get into this using `roscd ros_wkshop`. If you source `devel/setup.bash`, in the `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` you should have `~/catkin_ws/src` added. So you cannot access `ros_wkshop1` in the root of the workspace.

**Comment by [Nouman Tahir](https://answers.ros.org/users/20072/nouman-tahir/) on 2015-08-11**:
@Asaad Irfaan, can you share what exactly you are typing in the Terminal and also whether you are using the same terminal or trying the command in another.

**Comment by [Asaad Irfan](https://answers.ros.org/users/23193/asaad-irfan/) on 2015-08-11**:
THe issue was in the package. It wasnt built using the right commands. I deleted it and built it again as given in the tutorials and it worked.